# Virtual Box `*-1.1?-linux.vbox` files

Tags: upgrade, virtualbox, 23.04

After upgrading from Ubuntu 22.10 to 23.04, Virtual Box was also upgraded to version 7.0.6. Recently, I noticed that, besides the normal virtual machine definition files (e.g. `Windows11.vbox` or `Windows95.vbox`), some extra `vbox` files were created during or after the upgrade process, possibly containing backup info from the previous version.  The file names are like `Windows11-1.17-linux.vbox` or `Windows95-1.15-linux.vbox` and they predate the upgrade process.

Does any body have an idea of what these files are and whether they can safely be removed?